# How can I create a Viking/Saiyan that creates his own weapons with energy, ki or magic?

Tags: character-creation, multi-classing, pathfinder-2e

I'm going to play on a table with some friends and I wish to create a Viking-type warrior that is able to use energy/ki/magic to create weapons and fight like a barbarian but without being one. The character creation limitations are to be a lvl 5, using the core rulebook 2nd edition, advanced players guide and Lost omens: character guide, Gods and magic & Legends.

The concept would be a Viking/Saiyan, so it's starting from a low lvl 5 and the campaign is estimated to end up anywhere from lvl 8 to 10. Any magic that he learns is focused on the typical saiyan powers from dragon ball (flying, ki attacks, move absurdly fast and, if possible, visual indication of powering up like going super saiyan).

Comment: The flavor of the character isn't especially rules relevant, so it seems that the base of this question is "How can I create a character that magically conjures their own weapons?" Are you looking for something similar to the Kinetecists *Kinetic Blade* feature and/or the Gloomblade Fighters' *Shadow Weapons* feature from PF-1e?

Comment: Alternatively, are you more interested in the Ki elements? If you could do all that you mention above without explicitly summoning weapons? Perhaps the question would then become "How can I gain maximum Ki abilities while taking the Viking archetype?", or "How does <some ability from the Viking archetype, such as Viking Weapon Familiarity> interact with <some Monk ability, such as Flurry of Blows>?" Another alternative; the PF2e subreddit is a great place for open-ended build requests.

Comment: @RevenantBacon exactly, I have found ways to create weapons from magic but I would like a suggestion from someone with more knowledge, since this is my 1st character on PF2e

Comment: @ESCEI would really like to explore that option too, I'll ask on the subreddit, thanks for the suggestion